# how to Get The Code of part in stanford-nlp?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

hey all how can i get a code for a Stanford-nlp for example i need to see code for **named-entity recognition** or **relation extraction** is this Available or not ?
thanks in advance..

Comment: If it is opensource you can find in the website related to the project where the code is hosted

Comment: it's open source but the code is very huge , and i can't find what i want just if any know any way to get the code of specific pat of it

Comment: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP

Comment: this is the full code but i need the code which make the Tokenizer  or the code for relation extraction

Answer (score 0):

As comments have mentioned, the code is [open source on GitHub](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP). The various components are in packages. For example:

- The Named Entity Recognizer lives in [CRFClassifier](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier.java) (though CRFClassifier is more general than just named entity recognition).
- Relation extraction lives in a few places, depending on the extractor you want. I'm partial to the various implementations of the [KBPRelationExtractor](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/KBPRelationExtractor.java) interface.
- Tokenization happens in the [process package](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process) -- The heavy lifting happens in [this flex file](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBLexer.flex).